# TCSH tab auto complete with the part of current typed command

Tags: autocomplete, tcsh

I am trying to write my own complete for a command.
The completion needs to use a portion of the typed command to for a path search.

I am trying to get the following behavior

When I write `my_commad -ws my_ws -t[TAB]` a list of folders under my_ws/tests appears as a list of completion
I couldn't figure out how to break it

I tried the following, but failed because of quotes problem, I guess

```
complete my_command 'n@-t@`echo $COMMAND_LINE | perl -ne '/-ws (\w+)/; print $1'`@'
```

Comment: You've got to provide more details. Give us an example of what exactly you're trying to do. I assume you've read the man pages for `tcsh` and read about the autocomplete mechanism there. Didn't it help? Did you try anything?

Comment: I've edited my initial post with an example of what I tried

Comment: But you still haven't explained what you were trying to achieve.  There are lots of different completion options. Give a specific and clear example. "when I write xxx and press TAB, I want it to be completed to..."

Comment: When I write
`my_commad -ws my_ws -t[TAB]`

A list of folders under my_ws/tests appears as a list of completion

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that requirement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Quoting problem

The problem with your command, as you mentioned, is that you have single quotes inside your single quotes that you need to escape. There are couple of way to do that.

If your `backslash_quote` shell variable is set, you can escape the internal single quotes by a backslash.

```
complete my_command 'n@-t@`echo $COMMAND_LINE | perl -ne \'/-ws (\w+)/; print $1\'`@'
```

- You can check if it is by running `echo $?backslash_quote` and see that the value is 1.
- If it's not set, you can set it by running `set backslash_quote`

Alternatively, if your `backslash_quote` is not set and you don't want to change it, you can replace your internal single quotes with `'"'"'`.

```
complete my_command 'n@-t@`echo $COMMAND_LINE | perl -ne '"'"'/-ws (\w+)/; print $1'"'"'`@'
```

Both solutions would solve your quotes issue, and the result would be that the argument after `-t` would be complete by your argument for `-ws`.

```
$ my_command -ws my_ws -t TABmy_ws
```

Anyway, that's not what you're trying to achieve. You want it to be completed by the *"list of folders under my_ws/tests"*.

## Answering your actual requirements

For more complicated completions, you might consider to create a wrapper script that would parse your `$COMMAND_LINE` variable and perform additional actions.

For instance, if you want the argument after `-t` to be completed by the subdirectories under $WS/tests, you can write a script in your home directory similar to the following:

```
$ cat $HOME/findtest.sh
#!/bin/sh
ws=$(perl -ne '/-ws (\S+)/; print $1' <<< $@)
find $ws/tests -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null
```

And then in your `complete` command, you will call the `findtest.sh` script with your `$COMMAND_LINE` variable as the arguments:

```
complete my_command 'n@-t@`$HOME/findtest.sh $COMMAND_LINE`@'
```

#### Results:

Assuming that under `my_ws/tests` you have the following folders:

```
ls -1 my_ws/tests
test1
test2
test3
```

Then trying to complete the parameter for `-t` would result in:

```
$ my_command -ws my_ws -t TAB
my_ws/tests/test1 my_ws/tests/test2 my_ws/tests/test3 
$ my_command -ws my_ws -t my_ws/tests/test
```

If you don't want to show the full path, but just the directories under `my_ws/tests` without the leading path, you can change your `find` command in the script to:

```
find $ws/tests -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n" 2>/dev/null
```

Result:

```
$ my_command -ws my_ws -t TAB
test1 test2 test3 
$ my_command -ws my_ws -t test
```

### Additional recommendations

You can add additional features for your completion. For instance:

```
complete my_command 'n@-t@`$HOME/findtest.sh $COMMAND_LINE`@' 'N/-ws/(-t)/' 'n/-ws/d/' 'p/*/(-ws)/'
```

Or more readable:

```
complete my_command \
  'n@-t@`$HOME/findtest.sh $COMMAND_LINE`@' \
  'N/-ws/(-t)/' \
  'n/-ws/d/' \
  'p/*/(-ws)/'
```

Explanation:

- `'p/*/(-ws)/'` - at any place after your `my_command` it will try to complete to `-ws`.
- `'n/-ws/d/'` - after `-ws` it will try to complete only to directories.
- `'N/-ws/(-t)/'` - If two words before your current position in your line the word was  `-ws`, the next argument it expects is `-t`.

Notice that the order here is important, as `tcsh` will try to complete according to the order the words appear in the `complete` command. For instance, if you move the `'p/*/(-ws)/'` to the beginning, it will always try to complete to `-ws` and will not try the rest of the line.

##### Result:

```
$ my_command TAB                # will complete to -ws
$ my_command -ws 
$ my_command -ws mTAB           # will complete list of directories that start with m
$ my_command -ws my_ws/ 
$ my_command -ws my_ws/ TAB     # Will complete to -t
$ my_command -ws my_ws/ -t
$ my_command -ws my_ws/ -t TAB  # Will complete to list of folders under my_ws/tests
test1 test2 test3 
$ my_command -ws my_ws/ -t test
```